# Angular Object output 'undefined' in console. Can't get data into front end

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-services, angular-components

Here is the Json I got from one of the alphaAdvantage api endpoints:

```
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "CEF",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-05-15",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-05-15": {
            "1. open": "16.0200",
            "2. high": "16.1600",
            "3. low": "15.9900",
            "4. close": "16.1600",
            "5. volume": "1765403"
        },
        "2020-05-14": {
            "1. open": "15.7300",
            "2. high": "15.8700",
            "3. low": "15.7300",
            "4. close": "15.8700",
            "5. volume": "1125986"
        }
}
```

I believe I've set up all the interfaces needed to hold this data:

```
ITimeSeriesDaily{
    meta: Array<IMeta>;
    timeSeries: Array<ITimeSeries>;}
IMeta{ information: string; etc. }
ITimeSeries{ date: Array<IDate>; }
IDate{ open: number; etc }
```

Here's my data service:

```
export class StockService{
private stockUrl = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=CEF&apikey=demo';
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
    getStocks(): Observable<ITimeSeriesDaily[]>{
        return this._http.get<ITimeSeriesDaily[]>(this.stockUrl)
}}
```

and my component typescript:

```
export class FirstToolComponent implements OnInit {
timeSeriesDaily$: ITimeSeriesDaily[];
constructor(private  stockService: StockService){}
ngOnInit() {
    return this.stockService.getStocks()
      .subscribe(data => this.timeSeriesDaily$ = data),
      console.log(`HELLOO ${this.timeSeriesDaily$}`);
  };
}
```

In the console, the log outputs 'HELLOO undefined' and I cannot interpolate anything in my html template like this:

```
<div *ngFor='let timeSeriesDaily of timeSeriesDaily$'>
    <p>{{ timeSeriesDaily.meta }}</p>
</div>
```

It compiles so as far as I know I imported everything necessary. Do I have to define the nested objects in the Json? I haven't had much luck finding examples of this online. Thank you to all who read this far!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, inside your component you wrote a return function inside the ngoninit lifecycle of an angular which will not return you anything

The response you receive from an HTTP call was asynchronous in nature. The console will get executed even before you get the actual response from the HTTP Request, which caused it to print undefined in the console.

If you are interested in checking what is the response you received from an HTTP request you should add a console log inside the subscribe function itself

```
export class FirstToolComponent implements OnInit {
timeSeriesDaily$: ITimeSeriesDaily[];
constructor(private  stockService: StockService){}
ngOnInit() {
   this.getStocks();
}
getStocks() {
 this.stockService.getStocks()
      .subscribe(data => {
             this.timeSeriesDaily$ = data;
             console.log(`HELLOO ${this.timeSeriesDaily$}`);
            });

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's helpful. The log still outputs undefined. Could this be a problem with the api? if you follow the url in my service it should spit out valid Json. I posted it with the demo apikey but I use the free one they sent me in my code.

Comment: What is the status code you observed in network call when the request was fired ?

Comment: 200 from both the api and my localhost

Comment: It looks like alphaAdvantage uses the public repository StockJS (https://github.com/sockjs), not sure if this is relevant but here is the code that comes up when I go to localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1589730747727: {"websocket":true,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":false,"entropy":3988135574} the network call status is 200. I'm checking out some github conversations hoping to find an answer but I'm not sure this is a problem

Comment: Okay .. one quick think is try to verify that end point is working or not in postman.. just to make sure it has no problem with endpoint

Comment: Can you remove the typecasting at http get call and return type of that method and try to make a http call and see the response pass from service to component or not. Just to make sure that whether any problems with your interface typecasting or not